# Como puedo hacer que una imagen se reescale al ancho del viewport?

Tags: html, css, imagen, responsive

Queria hacer que en mi web se reescalen las imagenes al ancho del viewport de manera que se puedan ver enteras.

Tengo las cosas en porcentajes y estoy tratando de trabajarr con lo poquillo que se de responsive design, pero aqui me he perdido. Creo que lo mas normal seria hacer cosas con JS aunque como tengo 0 idea de JS, agradeceria que me dijerais tambien si hay alguna manera con css.

Comment: ayudaría leas por favor [ask], edites y mejores tu pregunta

Comment: No he encontrado nada en el foro sobre este problema especifico, habalan de cosas de bootstrap y js que no conozco, por eso he pedido ayuda especificamente para el css. He hecho otras preguntas ya, se que puedo incluir codigo y tal pero en esta concreta no tiene sentido incluirlo.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/width y acá para el tema del viewport https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

img{ width:100vw;} con esto puedes hacer que las imágenes sean el 100% del ancho del viewport, pero tienes que estar seguro que la imagen sea lo suficientemente ancha para que no se te pixele...te lo recomiendo más bien para móviles, no creo que lusca tan bien una imagen a todo ancho en desktops.. saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, no conocia el "vw"